Open boundary conditions in time
I want to simulate lattice QFT on lorentzian manifold, for my purposes it's necessary for time dimension to be non-compact. Both dirichlet and neumann boundary conditions are out of question since they introduce severe boundary effects. Does anyone know how to implement open boundary conditions for lattice field theory such that they wouldn't introduce severe boundary effects?

For people here to understand the problem, it would probably be useful to be more detailed and perhaps include formulas. In general, however, it would also be useful to hear what you found in the literature.
